# How to genenerate 24 random numbers between 1 and 24 in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, random

For this Wordpress site, I need to generate 24 variables each of which contains a number between 1 and 24. The problem is that two variables cannot have the same value. So I basically need to generate 24 variables each of which contains a number between 1 and 24.

Here's the code that I am using to generate a random number.

```
$mirza = rand(1,24);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any reason why you need 24 differently-named variables and can't just use an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = range(1,24);
shuffle ( $a );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `shuffle`

```
$numbers = range(1, 24);
shuffle($numbers);
```

Comment: @nico If only the ability didn't have a 20 second lag period.

Comment: How would i lets say store the shuffle values in 24 different variables?I tried this:
      $numbers = range(1, 24);
  $one = shuffle($numbers);
  $two = shuffle($numbers);
  echo $one;
  echo '<br />3';
  echo $two;

Comment: @mirza: `$numbers` is an array of 24 elements, so it is like having 24 variables. You just access them with `$numbers[0]`, `$numbers[1]`, and so on up to `$numbers[23]`. The whole point of using arrays is not to have lots of variables around. Of course you could do `$one = $numbers[0]`, `$two = $numbers[1]` etc. but that would be pointless.

Comment: @mirza: also, note that `shuffle` does NOT return a shuffled version of the array, it modifies the original variable. The return value is just the status of the call (`TRUE` or `FALSE` for success or failure)

Comment: @mirza if you are dead set no not using an array you could use list($a1, $a2, ... , $a24) = $numbers;  (fill in the ... with the rest of the variable names)